# Bitbucket symbol (arrow) meaning

Tags: git, bitbucket

What does the arrow mean? I'm not new to git or bitbucket but I think I may have messed something up in my inital commit and I need help to resolve this.

The folder in my local repo is not empty, but pulling it down to another location the folder is. Is it a link? Not on my local repo.

The folder is a part of the vendor-folder (as shown) and the silex-app was installed through composer.

This would be solved if I had control over the webserver but I don't - it's on a hosting web site.

Any and all help appriciated.

[image: screen dump from bitbucket.org]

Comment: Could be a _git submodule_.

Comment: oh... if that's so - how do update it? With `git pull` directly in that directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a git submodule. To initialize all your submodules in your local clone, you can use the following command:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

See ['git submodule update --init --recursive' VS 'git submodule foreach --recursive git submodule update --init'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057871/git-submodule-update-init-recursive-vs-git-submodule-foreach-recursive) or [Git update submodule recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168449/git-update-submodule-recursive)