# Git - folder not pushed to repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have been trying to push an entire folder to my repo on Bitbucket and I kept getting following when I view the source:[image]

I also check the commit to find it empty, Nothing was pushed. The folder was initially named ChartNew.js as result of a clone, so I tried renaming it mutiple times but I am still stuck with this issue.

Any idea how can I fix that.

---

UPDATE:

so I tried the second answer in [No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path and missing .gitmodules file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185365/no-submodule-mapping-found-in-gitmodule-for-a-path-thats-not-a-submodule) and yes the folders were removed successfully. I cloned the Charts repo to redo the push my repo but then I got stuck again with the same problem and the same issue in the screenshot above occured. :/

Comment: Git doesn't track directories. Does it contain any files?

Comment: yes the folder contains mutiple files but nothing was pushed to the repo

Comment: Those are not submodule entries? What happen if you clone that BitBucket repo? Do you see those folders empty? Do they fill up after a `git submodule update --init`?

Comment: @VonC I tried to clone the repo again but the folder ChartNewjs is empty. When pushed the first time, nothing inside it was pushed to the repo so basically nothing was there when I cloned again

Comment: @omarsafwany do you see a .gitmodule in your repo?

Comment: @VonC no it's not there

Comment: Strange, because you have the same picture in http://stackoverflow.com/a/30075692/6309

Comment: I ran the following command git submodule update --init --recursive but I got this response: No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'public/ChartNewjs'

Comment: Ok, can you try `git rm ChartNewjs` (no trailing /) and `git rm Charts`? Maybe the .gitmodule was deleted, and the gitlinks remains in the index. Then `add -A .` and commit and push.

Comment: @VonC Finally!!! git add -A . worked and the issue was fixed. Thank you

Comment: Great. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are submodule entries.

They are called **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, [special entries in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) of the pushed repo.

A submodule is made to record a specific SHA1 of a subrepo: see "[git submodule checks out the same commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30343691/6309)".

If a `.gitmodule` is no longer in the repo, then those gitlinks need to be removed:

```
git rm ChartNewjs # no trailing /
git rm Charts
git add -A . 
git commit -m "remove gitlinks submodules"
git push
```

---

[omarsafwany](https://stackoverflow.com/users/999885/omarsafwany) suggests in [the edit revision](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8192535):

> In case `git rm` didn't remove anything, then check the the answer "[No submodule mapping found in `.gitmodule` for a path that's not a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185365/no-submodule-mapping-found-in-gitmodule-for-a-path-thats-not-a-submodule)", in order to remove, then proceed with the above instructions.