# Recursively cloning a git repo doesn't pull submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'd like to clone a git repo [1], which has a submodule defined in `.gitmodules`:

```
[submodule "PointInCircle"]
        path = PointInCircle
        url = https://github.com/midas-journal/midas-journal-843
```

Following these questions [2-4], I tried:

```
$ git clone --recursive https://github.com/midas-journal/midas-journal-851
```

If I understand `submodule`s correctly, which I obviously don't, there should be a directory inside `midas-journal-851` called `PointInCircle` with the second repo cloned into it.  However, no `PointInCircle` directory is created and as far as I can tell the code isn't cloned anywhere.  For good measure, I also tried...

```
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule update
```

...as well as...

```
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
```

...and...

```
$ git submodule foreach --recursive git submodule update --init
```

...in the cloned directory.  Each command runs without printing anything to the console, and I don't see any changes in the directory.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

[1] https://github.com/midas-journal/midas-journal-851
[2] [Cloning a git repo with all submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200231/cloning-a-git-repo-with-all-submodules)
[3] [How to `git clone` including submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-to-git-clone-including-submodules)
[4] ['git submodule update --init --recursive' VS 'git submodule foreach --recursive git submodule update --init'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057871/git-submodule-update-init-recursive-vs-git-submodule-foreach-recursive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

You're not doing anything wrong. That repository's submodule is only partially configured.

[Submodules are defined by two things](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule):

> Submodules are composed from a so-called `gitlink` tree entry in the main repository that refers to a particular commit object within the inner repository that is completely separate. A record in the `.gitmodules` ... file at the root of the source tree assigns a logical name to the submodule and describes the default URL the submodule shall be cloned from.

This repository contains a `.gitmodules` file, but no `gitlink` objects.

GitHub [displays proper submodules with a grey folder icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584255/what-does-a-grey-icon-in-remote-github-mean), which is absent from this repository:

[image: GitHub submodule]

Since the faulty `.gitmodules` file only contains a single entry, in your case I recommend

1. deleting the `.gitmodules` file,

   ```
   git rm .gitmodules
   ```
2. adding the submodule properly,

   ```
   git submodule add https://github.com/midas-journal/midas-journal-843 PointInCircle
   ```
3. and committing.

   ```
   git commit -m "Fix PointInCircle submodule"
   ```

The output from `git commit` should show `PointInCircle` being added with mode `160000` (indicating a `gitlink`), and your repository should now be properly configured. Use `git submodule status` to be sure:

```
$ git submodule status
9bc2651367f8cc5f47ac5f6c708db2f9a71d8fd8 PointInCircle (heads/master)
```

You might want to open a pull request to the parent repository with your fix, but since it only contains a single commit from three years ago I suspect that it is abandoned.